# Draw polygon area over image using ReactJs library

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I display an HTML canvas element over an image and my goal is to create a **polygon area** using the mouse clicks of my user.

Continuously, the last clicked point should be connected with the initial one.

Does anyone know if there is a ReactJs library that can implement the above functionality?

Answer (score 1):

[React-designer](https://react-designer.github.io/react-designer/) comes for the rescue!